# RootViewController's view is not beeing resized with auto layout

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, autolayout

Hi when using autolayout on iOS 6, my "rootView" of my rootViewController doesnt seem to resize properly if at all.

My rootViewController is loaded from a nib and i am adding it to the view-hierarchy like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

RootVC *rootVC = [[RootVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootVC" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = rootVC;

return YES;
```

}

But when i rotate the simulator the view of rootVC doesnt resize. Since you cant set any constraints to the "rootview" in a xib, I also tried this but without any effect:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

RootVC *rootVC = [[RootVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootVC" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = rootVC;
NSArray *vConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view" : rootVC.view}];

NSArray *hConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view" : rootVC.view}];

[self.window addConstraints:vConst];
[self.window addConstraints:hConst];

return YES;
```

}

When i log-out the frame-size of the rootvc's view, it's always the portrait-format (w:768, h:1024)

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
NSLog(@"%f, %f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

}

could someone please tell me what i'm missing here? i've wasted hours with this problem and got nowhere^^

thx

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a lot of things can go wrong with the autolayout feature iOS 6.  Ambiguities in the constraints and failing to disable the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints in your view controllers can cause much conflict. So ensure there is no ambiguities in the constraints by calling the autolayoutTrace method in lldb: `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]` 
If there are ambiguities, you must resolve them.

Comment: after calling po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace], it just prints out the whole UI hierarchy, how to know that which one is causing the ambiguities